# Javascript: function calls not having parameters, but declaration do have parameters

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, arguments

I was wondering about how functions work in javascript, I noticed in some cases, things like [array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), [array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), and [event listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#the_event_listener_callback) the code that calls (not declares) the function (not using functionless or inline), usually `FunctionName` have parenthesis with the arguments in there (`FunctionName(arg1, arg2, arg3...)`). Are parameters “automatically” passed into the function?

Comment: I’m not sure what you’re asking—what do you mean by “automatically passed to the function”? That’s what parameters are; values/references passed to functions. In JS functions can be declared as *taking* parameters but callers may not *provide* some or all of the parameters; whether or not that’s “ok” is up to the function being called.

Comment: When you have a callback function, the function that receives it calls the function, and it passes arguments as necessary. E.g. `array.sort()` passes the two array elements that are being compared. `array.filter()` passes the element being tested, the index, and the array.

Comment: The code says I have these arguments. The code sends them to the function you provide. Just like how you code your own methods and you determine what to send to it.

Comment: @Dave Newton I meant that when you call it as a function (not as inline or functionless), the parameters are not explicitly there, like this: sort(compareFn) The last link was a typo, my bad.

Comment: You are giving it a function to call. It makes no difference.

Comment: @epascarello So you're saying that the operators, like sort and filter, have the parameters?

Comment: @AAsomb113 `sort` takes a parameter, a function used for comparison. The `sorter` function takes two parameters (two items from the collection being sorted). The `sort` function calls the `sorter` function like any other function. Functions can be passed as parameters, which is different than calling the function—the call happens later.

Answer (score 0):

Now I understand, looking [wikipedia's article on callback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)#JavaScript) looking at the alert, it looks like it first calls "calculate" first, supplies the 2 numbers and the function (that function name only, without the open and then closing parenthesis), and THEN uses the parameters for callbackFunction. So without the parenthesis on the function name is like without using bracket on an array name.